# Finding full taxonomy (heirarchical hypernymy sequence) of a given DBpedia resource using SPARQL

Tags: python, nlp, sparql, dbpedia

Given a DBpedia resource, I want to find the entire taxonomy till root.

For example, if I were to say in plain English, for Barack Obama I want to know the entire taxonomy which goes as *Barack Obama → Politician → Person → Being*.

I have written the following recursive function for the same:

```
import requests
import json
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")

def get_taxonomy(results,entity,hypernym_list):

    '''This recursive function keeps on fetching the hypernyms of the 
    DBpedia resource recursively till the highest concept or root is reached'''

    if entity == 'null':
        return hypernym_list
    else :
        query = ''' SELECT ?hypernyms WHERE {<'''+entity+'''> <http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym> ?hypernyms .}
        '''
        sparql.setQuery(query)
        sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
        results = sparql.query().convert()
        for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
            hypernym_list.append(result['hypernyms']['value'])
        if len(results["results"]["bindings"]) == 0:
            return get_taxonomy(results,'null',hypernym_list)
        return get_taxonomy(results,results["results"]["bindings"][0]['hypernyms']['value'],hypernym_list)

def get_taxonomy_of_resource(dbpedia_resource):
    list_for_hypernyms=[]
    results = {}
    results["results"]={}
    results["results"]["bindings"]=[1,2,3]
    taxonomy_list = get_taxonomy(results,dbpedia_resource,list_for_hypernyms)
    return taxonomy_list
```

The code works for the following input:

```
get_taxonomy_of_resource('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama')
```

Output:

```
['http://dbpedia.org/resource/Politician', 
'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Person', 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Being']
```

Problem :

But for following output it only gives hypernym till one level above and stops:

```
get_taxonomy_of_resource('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Steve_Jobs')
```

Output:

```
['http://dbpedia.org/resource/Entrepreneur']
```

Research:

On doing some research on their site `dbpedia.org/page/<term>` I realized that the reason it stopped at Entrepreneur is that when I click on this resource on their site, it takes me to resource 'Entrepreneurship' and state its hypernym as 'Process'. So now my problem has been directed to the question:

How do I know that Entrepreneur is directing to Entrepreneurship even though both are valid DBpedia entities? My recursive function fails due to this as in next iteration it attempts to find hypernym for Entrepreneur rather than Entrepreneurship.

Any help is duly appreciated

Comment: yeah, the common DBpedia "redirect trap". You can solve it via by using a property path, i.e. `query = '''SELECT ?hypernyms WHERE {<'''+entity+'''> 
        '''dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/<http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym> ?hypernyms  .}'''` - but be careful, redirects can change the meaning of the original word/entity and just refer to some related concept. In your example, "Entrepreneur" redirects to "Entrepreneurship" which itself has "Process" as hypernym. - this is clearly something that you don't want to have as hypernym of a person.

Comment: In general, hypernyms for named entities like persons, places etc. don't make any sense - not sure why you want those instead of following the type hierarchy here. Hypernyms should be used for things or abstract things in my opinion

Comment: Thanks a lot @AKSW for your highly informative answer. I was trying to find out how two entities are related by finding the first common "parent" or "hypernym" entity. But I realize that hypernyms are not making sense. Will incorporate type heirarchies instead. Thanks again for your valuable answer:)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this same problem before while writing a program to generate taxonomies and my solution was to use in addition [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) when my main ressource failed to provide a hypernym.

The wiktionary dump can be downloaded and parsed into a python dictionary.

*For example, the wiktionary entry for 'entrepreneur' contains the following:*

> Noun
>   entrepreneur (plural entrepreneurs)
>   A person who organizes and operates a business venture and assumes much of the associated risk.

From this definition, the hypernym ('person') can be extracted.

Naturally, this approach entails writing code to extract the hypernym from a definition (a task which is at times easy and at times hard depending on the wording of the definition).

This approach provides a fallback routine in cases when the main ressource (DBpedia in your case) fails to provide a hypernym.

Finally, as stated by AKSW, it is good to have a method to capture incorrect hypernym relations (e.g. Entrepreneur - Process). There is the area of [textual entailment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_entailment) in natural language processing, which studies methods for determining if a statement contradicts (or implies or .. ) another statement.

Comment: @Aneri Sheth: Glad to hear that! Don't forget to upvote the answer ;)